# missing ) after argument list? jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, apostrophe

Using the code below I can insert a new row to my table (`#courseelements`).

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
      $('#courseelements > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Helloworld</td></tr>');
    });
```

However, I'd like to replace the `Helloworld` with a `<select>` element. So something like this:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
      $('#courseelements > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>

        <select class='plan_id'>
            <option value='1'>Description</option>
            <option value='2'>Description</option>
            <option value='3'>Description</option>  
        </select>


      </td></tr>');
    });
```

But this gives me "missing ) after argument list" on the first apostrophe ' `<select class='`

Any ideas why?

Comment: des got it before I could, but you can even see in your question, the coloring is different for plan_id because it is being parsed as outside of the string

Comment: (This is why it pays to use an *appropriate* editor -- the kind that does syntax highlighting, indenting, perhaps even static analysis, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to escape quotes:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
  $('#courseelements > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>

    <select class=\'plan_id\'>
        <option value=\'1\'>Description</option>
        <option value=\'2\'>Description</option>
        <option value=\'3\'>Description</option>  
    </select>


  </td></tr>');
});
```

As alternative you can wrap whole appended string in double quotes insetead of single quotes:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
  $('#courseelements > tbody:last').append("<tr><td>

    <select class='plan_id'>
        <option value='1'>Description</option>
        <option value='2'>Description</option>
        <option value='3'>Description</option>  
    </select>


  </td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: If you go the escape route, you'll need to escape the quotes in `option value='1'`, etc., as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var select=$("<select class='plan_id'></select>")
    .append("<option value='1'>Description</option>")
    .append("<option value='2'>Description</option>")
    .append("<option value='3'>Description</option>");

 $('#courseelements > tbody')
.append($("<tr><tr>"))
.append($("<td></td>")
.append(select));
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TzZTA/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different quote type for the quotes inside your HTML than you do for the quotes surrounding the HTML:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
      $('#courseelements > tbody:last').append("<tr><td>

        <select class='plan_id'>
            <option value='1'>Description</option>
            <option value='2'>Description</option>
            <option value='3'>Description</option>  
        </select>


      </td></tr>");
    });
```

Comment: This gives me "unterminated string literal"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different quote marks.

```
select class="plan_id">
```

double here since the entire string is delimited with single.

Answer (score 1):

change the single quotes with double quotes inside the string-

```
<select class="plan_id">
            <option value="1">Description</option>
            <option value="2">Description</option>
            <option value="3">Description</option>  
        </select>
```

or escape them with `\` like-

```
<select class=\'plan_id\'>......
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to call $('').append through PHP echo, like this:

```
$info= "<div style=\'font-size:9px;\'>
    <img src=\'./img/filtro.png\'>Some tips
</div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#divTips').append('$info'); 
</script>";
```

Make sure replacing all your break lines before, like this:

```
$info= preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $info);
```